# return child post if available otherwise parent post

Tags: wp-query, query

How to use WP_Query (or direct sql) and return child post if available otherwise parent post?

Sample code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my-cpt',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

My target is that if any post (my-cpt) have child post then return last child otherwise return parent post.

Suppose: following my posts

- parent-1

  - child-1-parent-1
  - child-2-parent-1
- parent-2
- parent-3

  - child-1-parent-3

So i want to return by my query child-2-parent-1, parent-2 and child-1-parent-3

How to modify my query to achieve this?

Comment: This won’t be achievable in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need at least 2 queries for this task, since it's irregular.
For example

```
// collect all child posts
$allChildPosts = get_posts([
  'post_parent__not_in' => [0],
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
]);

// list child posts and filter one post by parent id
$childPosts = [];
foreach ($allChildPosts as $post) {
    $childPosts[$post->post_parent] = $post;
}

// get all parent level posts without descendants
$lonelyPosts = get_posts([
  'post_parent__not_in' => array_keys($childPosts),
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
]);

$allPosts = array_merge($childPosts, $lonelyPosts);
// As a drawback, you'd have to sort them manually, since they are glued together
usort($allPosts, 'sorting_function');
```

First approach utilizes only 2 db queries, but will become inefficient with large quantity of posts

Second approach:

```
// get all parent posts
$parentPosts = get_posts([
  'post_parent' => 0,
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
]);

$allPosts = [];
foreach ($parentPosts as $post) {
    $descendants = get_posts([
      'post_parent' => $post->ID,
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'orderby' => 'whatever'
    ]);
    if ($descendants) {
        $allPosts[] = $descendants[0];
    } else {
        $allPosts[] = $post;
    }
}
```

Second one is more straight-forward and also allows to order descendants (otherwise how to understand which of them must be last?), but since it makes `numberOfParentPosts + 1` queries it will become inefficient with large quantity of *parent* posts.

If you need really efficient solution, you'd have to write clever MySQL manually.

But feel free to prove me wrong :)